# setFieldValue is leaves to a cannot find variable issue in react-native formik?

Tags: react-native, expo

**Problem:**

I have created a formik form in my react-native application in there I am using react-native picker like this.

```
<View style={styles.FormGroup}>
                            <Picker
                              selectedValue={props.values.offenceId}
                              style={{ height: 30, width: "90%" }}
                              itemStyle={{
                                width: "50%",
                                borderWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: "##aaaaaa",
                                height: 44
                              }}
                              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                                setFieldValue("offenceId", itemValue)
                              }
                              onBlur={props.handleBlur("offenceId")}
                            >
                              <Picker.Item label="Select Offence" value={0} />
                              {this.renderOption()}
                            </Picker>
                          </View>
                          {props.touched.offenceId && props.errors.offenceId ? (
                            <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                              <Text>{props.errors.offenceId}</Text>
                            </View>
                          ) : null}
```

When running the application it is giving me this error.

> Can't find variable:setFieldValue

I tried a lot to find a solution to this issue but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: You haven't destructured formik props, so there is no declared `setFieldValue` field.

Comment: Just take it from the props given by Formik: `props.setFieldValue`.